# Stopping the flow (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Good day.
I am writing my first application for Android, so please do not kick.
The question is: at the moment when press the button, main stream does not stop, and listview is not updated on the basis of a new user request. I Spent near 7 hours, and already tried all that gave Google, but it never works.
I would be very-very glad of any help. (Id there any remarks about code - will be also very appreciated).

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public ArrayList<String> infoList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayAdapter infoAdapter;
    public ListView lv;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    public String userRequest;
    EditText eText;
    Button btn;
    NewThread thread;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        infoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.song_name, infoList);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thread.stopIt();
                userRequest = eText.getText().toString();
                infoList.clear();
                linkList.clear();
                infoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//*
                thread = new NewThread();
                thread.execute();
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final String downloadLink = linkList.get(position);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Downloading...");

                alertDialog.setMessage("Download " + infoList.get(position) + " ?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(downloadLink));
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

    }


    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {


            try {
                String url = String.format("http://zaycev.net/search.html?query_search=%s",
                        URLEncoder.encode(userRequest, "UTF-8"));
                String useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) " +
                        "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
                        "Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36";

                Elements nextPage;
                int number = 0;

                    do {
                        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(useragent).timeout(5000).get();
                        nextPage = doc.select("[class$=pager__item_last]");
                        Elements resultOfSearch = doc.getElementsByClass("search-page__tracks");
                        Elements elements = resultOfSearch.select("div[data-dkey]");


                        for (Element element : elements) {
                            String artName = element.select(".musicset-track__artist").text();
                            String trackName = element.select(".musicset-track__track-name").text();
                            String trackDur = element.select(".musicset-track__duration").text();

                            Document link = Jsoup
                                    .connect(element.select(".musicset-track__download-link")
                                            .attr("abs:href"))
                                    .userAgent(useragent)
                                    .timeout(5000)
                                    .get();

                            String trackLink = link.select("#audiotrack-download-link").attr("abs:href");

                            infoList.add(artName + " - " + trackName + ": " + trackDur);
                            linkList.add(trackLink);
                            number++;
                            publishProgress();

                        }
                        url = nextPage.attr("abs:href");


                    } while (nextPage.hasAttr("href") && number <= 200);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            lv.setScrollContainer(false);
            Parcelable state = lv.onSaveInstanceState();
            infoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //*
            lv.setAdapter(infoAdapter);
            lv.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        }

        public void stopIt() {
            if (thread == null) {
                return;
            }
            thread.cancel(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

I have updated code in doInBackground by adding "if(!isCancelled())", and now I have such logcat:

> 09-05 09:25:05.329 11037-11037/ru.startandroid.webparser E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
>   09-05 09:25:05.330 11037-11037/ru.startandroid.webparser E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
>   09-05 09:25:05.331 11037-11037/ru.startandroid.webparser E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131427413, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.ArrayAdapter)]
>                                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1562)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchModeChanged(AbsListView.java:3545)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnTouchModeChanged(ViewTreeObserver.java:879)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.ensureTouchModeLocally(ViewRootImpl.java:3340)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.ensureTouchMode(ViewRootImpl.java:3324)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$EarlyPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3823)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$EarlyPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
>                                                                                    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>                                                                                    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Comment: You notify your adapter of changes at every time except the one probably most important that is onPostExecute. Try it there. Also the adapter should be attached to list all the time while the list is visible. It should be attached in onCreate. I don't see a point of the code in onProgressUpdate, what is your goal here?

Comment: The goal of code in onProgressUpdate is to update data of ListView everytime when I get new element of it. As I know it's not the best way, but I work=)

Comment: where is the initialization the the NewThread?

Comment: @Khalid Taha, thread = new NewThread();

Comment: you are calling the method thread.stopIt() before initializing it, that will cause NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get problems. Do not mutate/change list of elements that used by adapter from other thread. This could lead to `OutOfBounds` crashes or `Race Conditions`. You could pass parsed strings to your `onProgressUpdate(String... parsed)` like so:

```
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        ....
        final String title = artName + " - " + trackName + ": " + trackDur;
        publishProgress(title, link);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... parsed) {
         //happens on UI thread so shouldn't cause problems
         infoList.add(parsed[0]);
         linkList.add(parsed[1]);
         infoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```